# Tense and meaning of, oh, also

Tags: past-tense, sequence-of-tenses, tense-agreement

I’m wondering about the progression of the tense and about how this shows time for the object moving in time.

> Oh, Also, I took all of the paper out of my office and put it in the middle room so that you can have better access to everything.

If the response is, “I got it, and I’m sorting it.”

Does the tense in the response correctly express a earlier past tense of time before the first action of the, “ I took.”

Comment: I don't understand your question. What does tense have to do with "Oh, also"? Why would "I got it" be an earlier past time before "took"? Surely you can't get the paper in the middle room before someone puts it there.

Comment: 'Oh, also...' merely suggests that the sentence was an afterthought to a previous statement about things the speaker has done.

Answer (score 1):

I take it that person A, the fist speaker, tells person B that s/he put the paper in the middle room, and then person B responds that s/he found the papers in the middle room and is sorting them. So the timeline would be:

1. Person A takes papers from the office to the middle room.
2. Person B finds papers in the middel room and starts to sort them.
3. Person A tells Person nB about the papers.
4. Person B resopnds, telling Person A that sorting is in progress.

But there is nothing in the tense or format of "*Oh, Also*" that confirms or establishes this timeline. Indeed those word don't have any particular tense. The verbs "*took*" and "*put*" are both in the past tense, which confirms that Person A moved the papers before telling person B about this action. The verb "*got*" is also in the past tense, confirming that Person B acted before telling Person A about it. The rest of the timeline is from the logic of the situation, not from anything inn the tenses.

Often this is true, much English speech does not have a fixed tense telling a listener when things happened or will happen. The logic of the situation must often be used to help determine the sequence of events.